# Geiger counter prime generation

Tags: code-golf, primes, radiation-hardening

This challenge is quite simple to conceptualise, but likely a lot harder to execute.

In this challenge, the program will have to detect the number N of its characters that have been randomly changed (at least half of the program will always remain). Then, it will have to output the Nth prime number.

A 'change' can only be the replacement of a character. You can assume it will always be replaced by something within your own language's alphabet.

## Rules

- Only half of your program (rounded down to fewer changes, if necessary) will ever be hit by radiation.
- Standard output formats apply.
- The prime number must always be correct. Regarding the 'Nth' prime, N can be 1- or 0-indexed.
- 1 is not a prime number!
- If nothing (or only 1 character, if you choose to make N 1-indexed) is changed, output 0/null/any falsey value.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
- Standard loopholes apply.

Comment: What kind of changes may happen? Is it possible that the very first character is changed into something outside of language alphabet, making code unacceptable by compiler/interpreter?

Comment: @DaniilTutubalin see now.

Comment: All of your recent challenges have been either put on hold or been very poorly recieved. I strongly suggest using [the Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) in the future to check community feedback and clear up obvious unintended loopholes before posting to main

Comment: I would suggest to change it this way: one (and exactly one) random character is changed. The program must find its index N and output Nth prime number. Or just output N (if its not a duplicate).

Comment: What counts as the language's alphabet?

Comment: Anything it can parse @SriotchilismOZaic

Comment: Closing as unclear because as the rules currently are, I could make a 1-character program that outputs 0 or null, and solutions longer than 3 characters seem impossible, which is probably not what the author intends.

Answer (score 1):

## GolfScript, <s>1</s> 0 bytes

Rule 1 + Rule 5. Thanks to @Jo King for mentioning that empty string is falsey value.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPkPBAA)

## GolfScript, 1 byte

0-indexed version which actually outputs a prime number (0th).

It is also JS and Python solution if we run it in interactive shell.

```
2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/3@j/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Unary](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Unary), 0 bytes

Outputs nothing as a falsey value for no change. Note that Unary only has one symbol in its alphabet, so any program outputting a falsey value would be valid, since there are no possible changes to be made.

Answer (score 0):

## Brainfuck, 1 byte

Outputs zero byte. Zero byte is falsey in Brainfuck.

```
.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9f7/9/AA)